# Your current logout threshold text box

Tags: users

I have added the [Automated Logout](https://www.drupal.org/project/autologout) module, now its working fine but in user edit page "Your current logout threshold text box" is showing up what is it. How to remove this please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `YOUR_SITE/admin/people/permissions`and under the ***Automated Logout*** section uncheck the ***Change own logout threshold*** option for ***authenticated user***.

[image]